# delete or edit wiki caterogies selection

Tags: wiki, wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki, categories

I'm able to create wiki categories columns, my problem is there are several wiki categories selections I want to delete or edit their name, but its seems that there is no option to do so. I can only add a new tag in to the list but not delete nor modify them.

Could anyone please help.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean meta tags when you mention Wiki Category Selection?

Comment: I mean the Wiki Category selection.

Comment: Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I just found out how! I'm using SharePoint 2013, and doing this on an enterprise wiki site.

Site settings > term store management tool > find your categories in the left column (mine was all the way at the end, in the site collection folder)

When you hover/click on the term, there should be a triangle that allows you to drop down and select delete.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: PS: If you want to just edit the category name, you can just double click on it in the normal "page edit > categories > add new item window"

Comment: Hi Melissa, Thanks for your solution. I still can't get it work, I guess may be because I have an older version of Sharepoint. There is no option for me to get to the drop down you shown.

Comment: Actually, I got confused. I'm using Office356 SharePoint, not sure if its the same as SharePoint2013